# React componentDid mount get Async image. if not done before changing page, how to cancel the request?

Tags: reactjs

I am kinda new to react coming from an Angular background. recently I am building a page where I display cards that all need to fetch an image from the microsoft graph api. The return type of the call is a base64 string. I don't want to put this into redux because it will make my devtools unreadable.

Therefore I decided to make a async call in the componentDidMount lifecycle hook with the this.isMounted pattern ([Cancel All Subscriptions and Asyncs in the componentWillUnmount Method, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52061476/cancel-all-subscriptions-and-asyncs-in-the-componentwillunmount-method-how)). The problem however is that for some reason this doesn't unsubscribe the async call that I made. I am not sure whether I made a mistake or whether it needs to be unsubscribed instead of checking whether the component is mounted. but I cannot find any information on how to deal with this.

Any help would be appreciated.

My teamCard code:

```
import React from "react";
import { Icon } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icon";
import TeamCardLogo from "./teamCardLogo/teamCardLogo";
import TeamCardPersona from "./teamCardPersona/teamCardPersona";
import { GetGroupMembers } from "../../HttpRepositories/graphRepository";
import { FormattedMessage } from "react-intl";
import Fade from "react-reveal/Fade";
import { Modal } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Modal";
import reactAppInsights from "react-appinsights";
import TeamModal from "./teamModal/teamModal";
```

class TeamCard extends React.Component {

```
    state = {
        members: "",
        modelIsOpen: false
    };

    async componentDidMount() {
        let members = await GetGroupMembers(this.props.id);

        if (this.state.member !== "error") {
            this.setState({ members });
        }
    }

    _openModal = id => {
        this.setState({ modelIsOpen: true });
    };

    _closeModal = () => {
        this.setState({ modelIsOpen: false });
    };

    render() {
        let members = "";

        if (
            typeof this.state.members !== "undefined" &&
            this.state.members.length > 0 &&
            this.state.members !== "error"
        ) {
            members = this.state.members.map((member, i) => {
                if (i < 5) {
                    return (
                        <div className="team-card-body__personas-wrapper-person" key={i}>
                            <TeamCardPersona
                                className="team-card-body__personas-wrapper-person"
                                member={member}
                                key={i}
                            />
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            });
        } else {
            members = <div className="no-members-spacer" />;
        }
        let favouriteIcon = "";

        this.props.isFavorite === true
            ? (favouriteIcon = <Icon iconName="FavoriteStarFill" />)
            : (favouriteIcon = <Icon iconName="FavoriteStar" />);

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {/* <Fade bottom delay={this.props.delay} appear={true}> */}
                <article
                    className="team-card-wrapper"
                    onClick={() => this._openModal(this.props.id)}
                >
                    <header className="team-card-wrapper__header">
                        <TeamCardLogo
                            injectClass="team-card-wrapper__header-photo"
                            teamId={this.props.id}
                        />
                        <div className="team-card-wrapper__header-options-wrapper">
                            <div className="header-options__icon-group">
                                <div className="header-options__group-type">
                                    <Icon iconName="LockSolid" />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div className="header-options__icon-group">
                                <div className="header-options__favourite">{favouriteIcon}</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </header>

                    <section className="team-card-body">
                        <h1>{this.props.title}</h1>
                        <h2>
                            {" "}
                            <FormattedMessage
                                id="teamcard.memberCount"
                                defaultMessage="Leden"
                            />
                            :{this.state.members.length}
                        </h2>

                        <div className="team-card-body__personas-wrapper">{members}</div>

                        <p className="description">{this.props.description}</p>

                        {/* <div className="team-card-body__join-button-wrapper">
                            <PrimaryButton text="Lid worden" />
                        </div> */}
                    </section>
                </article>
                {/* </Fade> */}
                <Modal
                    titleAriaId={this._titleId}
                    subtitleAriaId={this._subtitleId}
                    isOpen={this.state.modelIsOpen}
                    onDismiss={this._closeModal}
                    isBlocking={false}
                    containerClassName="team-modal-wrapper"
                >
                    <TeamModal
                        teamId={this.props.id}
                        title={this.props.title}
                        description={this.props.description}
                        favorite={this.props.isFavorite}
                        members={this.state.members}
                        closeModal={this._closeModal}
                    />
                </Modal>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default TeamCard;
```

my TeamCardLogo code (makes the async call)

```
import React from "react";
import { Icon } from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Icon";
import { getImage } from "../../../HttpRepositories/graphRepository";

class TeamCardImage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this._isMounted = false;
    }

    state = {
        groupImage: ""
    };

    getLogo = () => {};

    async componentDidMount() {
        this._isMounted = true;

        if (this._isMounted) {
            let logo = await getImage(
                `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/${
                    this.props.teamId
                }/photo/$value`
            );

            if (logo !== "error") {
                this.setState({ groupImage: logo });
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        let injectedClassName =
            this.props.injectClass != "" ? this.props.injectClass : "";
        let headerPhoto = "";
        const groupIcon = (
            <div className="team-card-wrapper__header-photo-alt">
                <Icon iconName="Group" />
            </div>
        );
        if (this.state.groupImage === "") {
            headerPhoto = groupIcon;
        } else {
            headerPhoto = <img src={this.state.groupImage} alt=" " />;
        }

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className={injectedClassName}>{headerPhoto}</div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this._isMounted = false;
    }
}

export default TeamCardImage;
```

my httpRepos code

```
import { getGraphToken } from "../adalConfig";
import axios from "axios";

export const GetGroupMembers = async groupId => {
    // we initiate a new token, to be sure that it didn't expire.
    let graphToken = getGraphToken();

    try {
        let response = await axios({
            url: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/${groupId}/members?$select=id,displayName`,
            method: "GET",
            headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + graphToken }
        });

        if (response.status != 200 && response.status != 204) {
            return "error";
        }

        return await response.data.value;
    } catch (error) {
        return "error";
    }
};

    export const getImage = async url => {
        // we initiate a new token, to be sure that it didn't expire.
        let graphToken = getGraphToken();

        try {
            let response = await axios({
                url: url,
                method: "get",
                responseType: "blob",
                headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + graphToken }
            });

            if (response.status != 200 && response.status != 204) {
                return "error";
            }

            var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
            var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(response.data);

            return await imageUrl;
        } catch (error) {
            return "error";
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check that `_isMounted` is still `true` before you call `setState`, not before you start the request.

```
async componentDidMount() {
  this._isMounted = true;

  let logo = await getImage(
    `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/${this.props.teamId}/photo/$value`
  );

  if (this._isMounted && logo !== "error") {
    this.setState({ groupImage: logo });
  }
}
```