# Combination of React HOC with fetch and redirect cause memory leaks

Tags: reactjs, memory-leaks, higher-order-components

I've created HOC which I use to fetch data and check, if user is logged in.
I use this HOC with Navbar to display different buttons, depending on wether user is logged in or not.

The issue is that if Im logged in (I store this info in localStorage) and load in a page login page (which has navbar), Im instantly redirected to main page (because i coded it that way) and but navbar is already waiting for fetch response and in console I get an error warning about memory leak.

How can I avoid it?
Some answer Ive looked up suggests checking, if component is still mounted, when receiving response from fetch, but im not sure, if its possible in the scenarion, where fetch is called inside a HOC. ([Cancel All Subscriptions and Asyncs in the componentWillUnmount Method, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52061476/cancel-all-subscriptions-and-asyncs-in-the-componentwillunmount-method-how/52061655))