# Intermittent test failure with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null` or `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null` error

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

We have intermittent test failures with `TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null` or `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null` error.

- Sometimes all tests succeed, the next time a random test fails
- The tests always work locally but fail intermittently in our CI pipeline
- Only the Axe (Accessibility) tests fail
- All failures point to the same line with `this.setState(...`

Here is a sample of one of the errors:

```
 FAIL src/views/SettingsView/SettingsView.test.js
   ● <SettingsView /> component › passes aXe test
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'createEvent' of null
       54 |         this.props.read().then((readSettings) => {
       55 |             if (readSettings.error) {
     > 56 |                 this.setState({ infoMsg: infoMsg.errorRead });
          |                      ^
       57 |             } else {
       58 |                 // api data name for destinationDirectory is s3address
       59 |                 this.showOnForm(readSettings.s3address, readSettings.email);
       at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:111:26)
       at invokeGuardedCallback (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:256:31)
       at commitPassiveEffects (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18248:9)
       at wrapped (node_modules/scheduler/cjs/scheduler-tracing.development.js:207:34)
       at flushPassiveEffects (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:18292:5)
       at Object.enqueueSetState (node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11040:5)
       at SettingsForm.setState (node_modules/react/cjs/react.development.js:335:16)
       at src/views/SettingsView/SettingsForm.js:56:22
 (node:99) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'body' of null
 (node:99) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 2)
 (node:99) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here is one of the tests:

```
import React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { axe } from 'jest-axe';
import SettingsForm from './SettingsForm';
import SettingsView from './SettingsView';
describe('<SettingsView /> component', () => {
    it('renders correctly <SettingsForm/> sub-component', () => {
        const component = mount(<SettingsView />);
        expect(component.find(SettingsForm)).toHaveLength(1);
    });
    it('passes aXe test', async () => {
        const wrapper = mount(<SettingsView />);
        expect(await axe(wrapper.html())).toHaveNoViolations();
    });
});
```

Here is the code:

**SettingsView:**

```
import React from 'react';
import SettingsForm from './SettingsForm';
import validate from './FormValidator';
import validateSimple from './SimpleFormValidator';
import UploadApi from '../../api/UploadApi';

const SettingsView = () => (
    <SettingsForm
        read={UploadApi.getSettingsApi}
        save={UploadApi.setSettingsApi}
        send={UploadApi.uploadSettingsApi}
        validate={validate}
        validateSimple={validateSimple}
    />
);
export default SettingsView;
```

**SettingsForm:**

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Form, Container } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'views/SettingsView//style.less';
import BannerMessage from './components/BannerMessage';
import InputLocalDirectory from './components/InputLocalDirectory';
import InputDestinationDirectory from './components/InputDestinationDirectory';
import ButtonSubmit from './components/ButtonSubmit';
import ButtonClear from './components/ButtonClear';
import ButtonSave from './components/ButtonSave';
import SavePrompt from './components/SavePrompt';
import InputEmail from './components/InputEmail';
import InfoBox from './components/InfoBox';
import Title from './components/Title';
import Label from './components/Label';
import infoMsg from './InfoMsg';

const initState = {
    // controls the save form button
    saveButtonEnabled: false,
    // controls the submit form button
    submitButtonEnabled: false,
    // displays a message beneath the page title
    message: 'Send files from your local machine to the server',
    // indicates what info to display
    infoMsg: infoMsg.noInfo,
    // form fields:
    inputLocalDirectory: '',
    inputDestinationDirectory: '',
    inputEmail: '',
};

/**
 * Settings form component
 *
 * Props:
 *     save - function which saves form fields: destination and email
 *     send - function which sends/submits form data
 *     read - function which reads saved form fields: destination and email
 *     validate - function which validates form fields
 *     validateSimple - function which enforces mandatory form fields
 *
 */
export default class SettingsForm extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = initState;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        // Reads saved form fields and display them on the form.
        // Displays read error when an error occurred during read.
        this.props.read().then((readSettings) => {
            if (readSettings.error) {
                this.setState({ infoMsg: infoMsg.errorRead });
            } else {
                // api data name for destinationDirectory is s3address
                this.showOnForm(readSettings.s3address, readSettings.email);
            }
        });
    }

    onClearClick = () => {
        this.setState(initState);
    };

    /** Validates and saves form fields
     * Displays validation error when an error occurred during validation
     * @param {object} event - The event
     */
    onSaveClick = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        // ! form validation accepts a boolean for disabling local directory selection
        const validation = this.validateSaveForm(this.state);
        if (validation.valid) {
            const saveResponse = await this.props.save({
                localDirectory: this.state.inputLocalDirectory,
                destinationDirectory: this.state.inputDestinationDirectory,
                email: this.state.inputEmail,
            });

            if (saveResponse.ok) {
                this.setState({ saveButtonEnabled: false, infoMsg: infoMsg.successUpdate });
            } else {
                this.setState({ saveButtonEnabled: true, infoMsg: infoMsg.errorUpdate });
            }

        } else {
            this.setState({ saveButtonEnabled: false, infoMsg: validation.infoMsg });
        }
    };

    /** Validates and submits form fields
     * Displays validation error when an error occurred during validation
     * @param {object} event - The event
     */
    onSubmitClick = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const validation = this.validateForm(this.state);
        if (validation.valid) {
            const submitResponse = await this.props.send({
                localDirectory: this.state.inputLocalDirectory,
                destinationDirectory: this.state.inputDestinationDirectory,
                email: this.state.inputEmail,
            });

            if (submitResponse.ok) {
                this.setState({ submitButtonEnabled: false, infoMsg: infoMsg.successUpload });
            } else {
                this.setState({ submitButtonEnabled: true, infoMsg: infoMsg.errorUpdate });
            }

        } else {
            this.setState({ submitButtonEnabled: false, infoMsg: validation.infoMsg });
        }
    };

    showOnForm(s3address, email) {
        this.setState({
            inputDestinationDirectory: s3address || '',
            inputEmail: email || '',
        });
    }

    /** Saves form into the state.
     * If all fields have non-blank value enable the apply button
     * @param {object} event - The event
     */
    handleChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
            infoMsg: infoMsg.noInfo,
        }, () => {
            this.setState({ saveButtonEnabled: this.validateSaveFields(this.state) });
            this.setState({ submitButtonEnabled: this.validateBasic(this.state) });
        });
    };

    /**
     *  Validates form for size and format
     * @param {object} form - The form values
     */
    validateForm(form) {
        return this.props.validate(form.inputDestinationDirectory, form.inputEmail, form.inputLocalDirectory);
    }

    /**
     *  Validates form for size and format
     * @param {object} form - The form values
     */
    validateSaveForm(form) {
        return this.props.validate(form.inputDestinationDirectory, form.inputEmail);
    }

    /**
     * Validates that save fields have non-empty values
     * @param {object} form - The form values
     */
    validateSaveFields(form) {
        return this.props.validateSimple([form.inputDestinationDirectory, form.inputEmail]);
    }

    /**
     * Validates that all fields have non-empty values
     * @param {object} form - The form values
     */
    validateBasic(form) {
        return this.props.validateSimple([form.inputEmail, form.inputLocalDirectory, form.inputDestinationDirectory]);
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Form id="settings-form" className="simple-form">
                    <Title text="File Uploader" />
                    <BannerMessage message={this.state.message} />
                    <InfoBox variant={this.state.infoMsg.variant} show={this.state.infoMsg.show} text={this.state.infoMsg.text} />
                    <div className="form-rows">
                        <Label label="FROM" />
                        <InputLocalDirectory value={this.state.inputLocalDirectory} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-rows">
                        <Label label="TO" />
                        <InputDestinationDirectory value={this.state.inputDestinationDirectory} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-rows">
                        <Label label="NOTIFY" />
                        <InputEmail value={this.state.inputEmail} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-rows">
                        <SavePrompt />
                        <ButtonSave onClick={this.onSaveClick} enable={this.state.saveButtonEnabled} />
                    </div>

                    <div className="form-rows, form-buttons">
                        <ButtonSubmit onClick={this.onSubmitClick} enable={this.state.submitButtonEnabled} />
                        <ButtonClear onClick={this.onClearClick} />
                    </div>
                </Form>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

SettingsForm.propTypes = {
    save: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    send: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    read: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    validate: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    validateSimple: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};
```

Update:

- `UploadApi.getSettingsApi` is `async` and calls `fetch()`
- I mocked `fetch()` by following: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-fetch-mock
- I unmounted all mounted components in the tests:

```
it('renders correctly <SettingsForm/> sub-component', () => {
    const component = mount(<SettingsView />);
    expect(component.find(SettingsForm)).toHaveLength(1);
    component.unmount();
});
```

- However there is now this warning when executing tests:

```
    PASS  src/views/SettingsView/SettingsView.test.js
      ● Console

        console.error node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:506
          Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.
              in SettingsForm (created by SettingsView)
              in SettingsView (created by WrapperComponent)
              in WrapperComponent
```

I came across https://stackoverflow.com/a/52061655/6134928 but it feels like a workaround.

Comment: can you share the rest of the `SettingsForm` component?

Comment: @EdgarHenriquez The complete component code was shared above. Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: no problem, have you taken a look at this https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/3482#issuecomment-347347454 ? seems that there's a little "hack" you can do for this to work

Comment: @EdgarHenriquez are you referring to unmounting of the components being tested? Yes, I have tried that before with no success.

Comment: what about adding a `catch` to your promise call? seems like your test is complaining about  `unhandledPromiseRejection`

Comment: @EdgarHenriquez great observation. I added `catch` and updated the original post.

Comment: Yes, the url that I sent you has that exact workaround but I didn't want to copy and paste that answer here since it's not my solution. The problem that you have now is that you unmount your component but your promise is still active, so by the time you get a response you then update the state (component already unmounted) so you get that error...

Comment: Liked your spirit @EdgarHenriquez awesome!